# SQL Server: Search values of type "varchar" with parameters of type "date"

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have a column "Uploaded" of type varchar(25). It has datetime values. Since the string stored in this column is not valid date(front-end is passing them. No control over there) it is kept as varchar(25). The strings stored in it are like:

**2016:04:14 21:20:35

2016:04:14 21:20:35

2016:04:14 21:20:35**
.
.
.

I need to compare these values in a search query

```
Select * from Table where [Uploaded] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

@StartDate and @EndDate are date type variables. Obviously the above query won't work. So, I have 2 ways:
1. Write correct query that can compare the passed date type variables with the "Uploaded" column. 
2. Update the [Uploaded] column values and re-store them as a valid datetime type.

How can that be achieved? Can someone help me writing either the correct search query or update all the records to convert them in valid datetime type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got `:` between year, month and day in `[Uploaded]` field then use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE CAST(REPLACE(LEFT([Uploaded],10),':','-') as date) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

If `datetime` needed then:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE CAST(REPLACE(LEFT([Uploaded],10),':','-') + RIGHT([Uploaded],9) as datetime) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: In this statement it will not compare time.

Comment: From OP question: *@StartDate and @EndDate are **date** type variables*

Answer (score 0):

This will give you accurate result.

```
    select * from Table where cast(replace(left([Upholded],10),':','-')+right([Upholded],len([Upholded]-10) as datetime) between @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2016:04:14 21:20:35' to data type int.

Answer (score -1):

you can cast the string data to a datetime value and then use datetime comparison

```
Select * from Table where CAST( [Uploaded] as Date) BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
```

make sure you use the right format for your datetime conversions and you should be golden.

here's some more info : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Comment: SELECT CAST('2016:04:14 21:20:35' AS DATE) AS [SampleDate] fails. The above query doesn't execute as well. Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: It will give conversion error. Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.